# Get index of two biggest values

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I got an array like `myArray[4] = { 10, 3, -5, 30 };` and I'D like to get the indexes of it's two elements with the biggest value (element in this case `30, 10`) and the indexe of `30` is `3` while the index of `10` is `0` *(zero based of course)*.

So the result should be `{3, 0}` because the index of the biggest element (30.0) is 3 and the index of the second biggest element (10.0) is 0.

---

How to implement a easy working solution for the problem?

```
double myArray[4] = { 10, 3, -5, 30 };
double biggestElement_1 = *std::max_element(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray));
int biggestElement_1_indx = find(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), biggestElement_1) - std::begin(myArray);
cout << biggestElement_1_indx << endl;

// How to go on to find the second biggest element ?
```

**Note**: I'm obviously new to C++ so sorry for the (stupid) **beginner** question - however: Any help would be very appreciated. `:)`

Comment: Sort the array and grab the last 2?

Comment: @Borgleader he want the index if he sort the index will be wrong

Comment: ... Please have another look at my question. I'm sure you will get it right this time :) Tip: It's about the indexes not the values. @Borgleader

Comment: `max_element` returns an iterator. You can use it compute the index directly (as diff between it and `begin()`), no need for `find`. But this task is easily solvable with one range for loop in a straightforward way. just think how you'd do that regardless of the programming language.

Comment: @codekaizer Just realized that, reopened.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I think you mixed something up but the question might be a duplicate but 100% NO duplicate of the linked one. I'd like to get the indexes while the OP of the linked one tries to get the values. So please undo the mark.

Comment: @jonas00 Of course my bad, [same idea one extra indirection](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94232cdd39a92fba) ([once more](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85da70187c191298) with std::array, should work just as well with std::vector)

Comment: Come on guys, altering the array is cheating!

Comment: @YSC Is not cheating if you restore the original situation afterwards.

Comment: @NiVeR I'm good with that one, even though I feel it's wrong somewhere :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vector of pairs` to save your array with their index, then sort them based on the value, and return the biggest values as you want, like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  double myArray[4] = { 10, 3, -5, 30 };
  vector<pair<double, double > >vec;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    vec.push_back(make_pair(myArray[i],i));
  }

  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
    cout<<vec[i].first<<" "<<vec[i].second<<endl;
  }

  cout<< vec[vec.size()-1].second<< ", "<<vec[vec.size()-2].second;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i appreciated @YSC

Comment: Using the vector `{ 30.5, 3, -5, 30 }` the result should get "0, 3" but it gets `"3, 0"`. Note: `Fix this declaring vector<pair<double, double > >vec; instead of int.`

Comment: ok. you can change the order by changing the index like this `cout<< vec[vec.size()-2].second<< ", "<<vec[vec.size()-1].second;`

Comment: if it works well, please accept the answer and upvote it. @jonas00

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the indexes of the *two* largest values easily with the `<algoritm>`'s functions (unless of course you're OK with altering the array). You'd better roll your own.

```
template <class InputIt>
auto two_biggest(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
{
    auto result = std::make_tuple(0, 0);
    // iter in [begin; end) and save result.get<0> and result.get<1>
    // let as an exercise (it's an exercise, right?)
    return result;
}
```

You then will be able to call it with:

```
auto t = two_biggest(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

or better yet, with C++17 tuple unpacking:

```
[largest, second_largest] = two_biggest(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Or for pre-C++17:

```
int largest, second_largest;
std::tie(largest, second_largest) = two_biggest(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Comment: You'll need to take care of special cases, especially: what happens when there is less than 2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to find the largest value in the array: just scan through it, and keep track of the largest value that you've seen so far. When you reach the end, that's the largest value.

Finding the second largest value is just as simple: when you do the scan for the largest value, if you find a value that's larger than the largest value you've seen so far, that's the new largest value, **and** the largest value that you've seen so far is now the second largest value.

In code:

```
std::pair<int, int> get_two_largest(int* ptr, int size) {
int largest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int second_largest;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    if (largest <= ptr[size]) {
        second_largest = largest;
        largest = ptr[size];
    }
return std::pair<int, int>(largest, second_largest);
}
```

I used `<=` for the comparison because with plain `<` (which is what I would use to find the largest value), the function would return a bad result for an array with all equal values.